# Summary of estimator properties (consistency, bias, sufficiency, etc.)

Tags: bias, estimators, consistency, sufficient-statistics, efficiency

I've read about various properties of estimators, but I'm wondering if there's some source with a summary (maybe a list, table, or graphic) of the properties for different kinds of estimators.  Scattered across my textbook and notes are various properties, for example:

- MLEs are asymptotically unbiased, and asymptotically normal
- MLEs are consistent
- Method of moments estimators are consistent

I'm wondering if there's a book, website, or some other source that summarizes these kinds of estimator properties and others in a single location.

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about what kinds of "relationships" you seek to characterize?  It's not clear whether you want to compare *estimators* or compare *properties*.

Comment: Could you also tell us why you found the textbook(s) missing in that respect to the point you had to ask X validated?